# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'one'

Tags: python, valueerror

```py
def admin():

    def admin_try():
        print ("1) Ver lista de productos.",'\n')
        print ("2) Agregar un producto.",'\n')
        print ("3) Modificar un producto (Precio).",'\n')
        print ("4) Eliminar un producto.",'\n')
        print ("5) Pedidos agendados.",'\n')
        print ("6) Salir.",'\n')
        global opcion
        opcion = int(input("Indique una opción valida: "))

    while True:
        try:
            admin_try()
        except (ValueError):
            print ("La instrución debe ser numerica.")
        admin_try()

admin()  # I get an error
```

I get an error when executing this code and I want to cycle with try,
and I get this error at the time of executing the code.  What I want is that whenever the user puts that wrong, the function is always executed.

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "g:/proyecto/try.py", line 15, in admin
>       admin_try()
>     File "g:/proyecto/try.py", line 11, in admin_try
>       opcion = int(input("Indique una opción valida: "))
>   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'uno'
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "g:/proyecto/try.py", line 20, in <module>
>    admin()
>   File "g:/proyecto/try.py", line 18, in admin
>   admin_try()
>   File "g:/proyecto/try.py", line 11, in admin_try
>   opcion = int(input("Indique una opción valida: "))
>   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'one'`

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use `try-except`:

- The need to use `try-except` arises from converting the input to an `int`

  - If you try to convert a non-numeric input to `int`, a `ValueError` `exception` will occur
  - This code can be executed without converting to an `int`
- Use the [membership operator, `in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) to determine if the input is in the `list` of accepted inputs.  If the input is not in the list, `admin()` is called again.
- Setting `opcion` as a global variable is not required.

  - If it's required outside of `admin()`, use `return`.
  - If `opcion` is required as an `int` outside of the `admin()` function, then use `return int(opcion)`

```py
def admin():
    print ("1) Ver lista de productos.",'\n')
    print ("2) Agregar un producto.",'\n')
    print ("3) Modificar un producto (Precio).",'\n')
    print ("4) Eliminar un producto.",'\n')
    print ("5) Pedidos agendados.",'\n')
    print ("6) Salir.",'\n')
    opcion = input("Indique una opción valida: ")

    while True:
        if opcion in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']:
            return opcion  # return the value if it's needed outside of admin()
            break  # stops the loop because a correct option has been selected
        else:
            print ("La instrución debe ser numerica.\n")
            admin()

admin()
```